# How to delete a newly appended list item that contains a children button

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to code a multi section user created list application,
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9KRQ.png)

That allows a user to enter text into an input field and depending on what button is clicked, will determine which section the new list item will be added to.... Now my current jquery code --

```
.append('< li >' + $('.userTextInput').val() + '< button class="deleteButton" >DELETE< /button >')
```

which gives a button element in the new list item i want to use to allow a user to delete a list item if it is no longer wanted there.

Im trying to use the new button created along with the li, if clicked remove the parent li, 
I want to use to remove the parent list item when clicked via jquery. I tried this so far.. with no luck...

```
$('.deleteButton').on('click',removeParentLi());

function removeParentLi() {

    $(this).parent().remove(); 

};
```

Comment: change **$('.deleteButton').on('click',removeParentLi());** to **$('.deleteButton').on('click',removeParentLi);**. Remove **()** in the **on**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this snippet, (for dyanamically added button(elements) use jQuery .on function for its parent)

```js
$('#add').click(function(){
var itemToAdd = $('#itemToAdd').val();
$("#list").append('<li>'+itemToAdd+' <button class="remove">X</button></li>')
});

$('#list').on('click','.remove',function(){
$(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="itemToAdd" />
<button id="add">Add</button>

<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, this totally helped me understand what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

2 little errors there. First, you bind the event but the list item may not even be there yet. The trick for this is to use event delegation, we add the event on a DOM node that will always be there and tell jQuery to fire it only when a specific children is clicked. That's heavy words, but the code is easy.

The second problem is that when defining the handler, you passed the result of your function (because you added the ()) instead of passing the function itself!

```
$("#myList").on('click','.deleteButton',removeParentLi);

function removeParentLi() {
    $(this).parent().remove(); 
};
```

The code assumes that your list has the id `myList` but we could very well add the event directly on the document body, but it would make javascript handle it on ALL clicks... I've kept your function intact, as it works fine, I just removed the () in the event handler definition.